# Combine two lists of entities with a condition

Tags: c#, linq, list, intersect, except

Say I have a class defined as

```
class Object
{
    public int ID { get;set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Object Item = obj as Object;
        return Item.ID == this.ID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + ID.GetHashCode();
        return hash;       
    }
}
```

And two lists, defined like so:

```
List<Object> List1;
List<Object> List2;
```

These two lists contain objects where `ID` fields could be the same, but `Property` fields may or may not. I want to have a result of all objects contained in `List1` together with all objects contained in `List2, with the condition that`Property`field must be set to`"1"`if it is set to`"1"` in any of those lists. The result must contain distinct values (distinct IDs).

For example, if we have 2 lists like this:

```
List1 
-----  
ID = 0, Property = "1"
ID = 1, Property = ""
ID = 2, Property = "1"
ID = 3, Property = ""

List2
-----
ID = 1, Property = "1"
ID = 2, Property = ""
ID = 3, Property = ""
```

I need a result to look like this:

```
Result
-------
ID = 0, Property = "1"
ID = 1, Property = "1"
ID = 2, Property = "1"
ID = 3, Property = ""
```

Currently it works like this:

```
var Result = List1.Except(List2).Concat(List2.Except(List1));
var Intersection = List1.Intersect(List2).ToList();
Intersection.ForEach(x => {
    x.Property = List1.Single(y => y.ID == x.ID).Property == "1" ? "1" : List2.Single(y => y.ID == x.ID).Property == "1" ? "1" : "";
});

Result = Result.Concat(Intersection);
```

...but ForEach is very slow. Can someone suggest a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = List1.Concat(List2)
                  .GroupBy(o => o.ID)
                  .Select(g => new Object() { 
                                   ID=g.Key,
                                   Property=g.Any(o=>o.Property=="1")?"1":""
                   })
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = List1.Concat(List2)
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.Property)
        .GroupBy(g => o.ID)
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .ToList();
```